# Using Python Pandas to Create a Pivot Table from Different Length Excel Files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read a bunch of excel files that contain stock weightings for different companies in a certain index, and turn that into one big pivot table that contains the dates, the tickers, and the weightings of each ticker on each date. In my code, I read the specific columns from the excel files and rename them. Then I make a list of the file dates and write each date the number of times as the excel file so I can add it into the data frame as a column, so I can use the pivot_table command. This is my problem, as the excel files are different lengths, so there is no specific number of times to write each date so that it lines up correctly. I tried using the pd.Series() command and it didn't work correctly either. Any help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if I can provide anything else to make this easier.

I have spent a lot of time on it but can't get it down completely to where it lines up perfectly, and keep getting this error, which I think is caused by the excel files being different lengths:

```
 ['6/27/2019', '6/26/2019', '5/14/2019', '5/15/2019', '6/19/2019', '6/18/2019', '6/13/2019', '6/12/2019', '5/20/2019', '5/21/2019', '5/3/2019', '5/2/2019', '4/1/2019', '5/9/2019', '5/8/2019', '6/4/2019', '6/5/2019', '6/3/2019', '5/30/2019', '5/31/2019', '6/20/2019', '6/21/2019', '5/13/2019', '6/14/2019', '5/27/2019', '6/7/2019', '6/6/2019', '5/1/2019', '4/2/2019', '5/23/2019', '5/22/2019', '6/10/2019', '6/11/2019', '5/17/2019', '5/16/2019', '6/24/2019', '6/25/2019', '5/29/2019', '5/28/2019', '6/28/2019', '5/24/2019', '6/17/2019', '5/10/2019', '5/7/2019', '5/6/2019']
5445
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "QQQReader2.py", line 32, in <module>
    df['FileDates'] = newDates
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3370, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3445, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3630, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 519, in sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Also, here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

path = r'/path/to/my/file'
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    os.chdir(path)
    data = pd.read_excel(f, header = None, footer = None, skiprows = 5, skipfooter = 3, usecols = 'D,E,J')
    df = df.append(data)

df = df.rename(columns = { 3:'Date', 4:'Weight', 9:'Ticker'})

fileDates = []
fileDates.extend(df.loc[0,'Date'])
print(fileDates)

for i in range(len(fileDates)):
    newDates = np.repeat(fileDates, len(data))


print(len(newDates))
df['FileDates'] = newDates
#print(df['FileDates'])


pivot = df.pivot_table(index = 'FileDates', columns = 'Ticker', values = 'Weight', aggfunc = 'first')
print(pivot)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('myDataFrame.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'DataFrame')
#pivot.to_excel(writer, 'DataFrame')
writer.save()
```

[I know it may not help but here is a picture of part of my data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6vKi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help with your error, but I use this pattern to only combine the dataframes one time.

```
df_list = []
for f in files_xls:
    temp_df = pd.read_excel(...)
    df_list.append(temp_df)

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```